# Unable to install windows driver for Belkin n600 DB

Tags: networking, ndiswrapper

I put together a linux computer from an old ATX desktop. It is an MB ASROCK|B85M PRO4 LGA1150 board with an Intel i5 4460 3.2G 6M R chip (i686). Forgive me, I am not the most tech savvy, but I'm trying.

So, I'm in the basement, and I tried fishing ethernet cable down, but this house is from the 30s and I'm not having much luck. I went to buy a wireless card, only to find that best buy only carries wireless USB sticks. So, I bought one, only to find out that it only has Windows drivers (I love and hate how my projects can become so labyrinthine from moment to moment).  So online, I find that I need to install and use the NDISWrapper program. I think I have it installed, but now I am stuck. How do I install the Windows Belkin driver? I'm a total amateur-hour case and probably need my hand held through the command line stuff. The last time I used the command line was in MS-DOS in 1993, and my old DOS commands don't work here!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu should recognize your wifi usb stick. If it's not for some odd reason, I'd suggest you exchange it for Wifi extender, or Wall-plug range extender (one that you plugin into power outlet in one room and another one plug in the basement). Both of those options will allow you to connect via ethernet cable and it should work 100%. Plus you'll get a better speed/link if you use power wall plug extender.

Comment: I would rather get it working through what I have. Thanks though I will look elsewhere for an answer.